# how to prevent navigator to insert data into input html angular

Tags: html, angular

I have two input fields that take values automatically from the browser in my Angular project, I tried with the option HTML autocompete, but it’s not changed.
this is my HTML Code:

```
 <div class='name' *ngIf="COMPTE_FRANCAIS==true">

            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]="driver.loginAm"
              [placeholder]="'DRIVERS.FORM.LOGIN' | translate" [matTooltip]="'DRIVERS.FORM.LOGIN' | translate">
            <input type="password" autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]="driver.pwdAm"
              [placeholder]="'DRIVERS.FORM.PWD' | translate" [matTooltip]="'DRIVERS.FORM.PWD' | translate">

            <a href="https://authps-espacepro.ameli.fr/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"
              style="margin-top: auto;">
              <button class="btn btn-ameli">
                <img src="./../../../../assets/img/ameli.png">
              </button>
            </a>

      </div>
```

and this is a screenshot for the problem:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i08Hd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to add new-password to the autocomplete in the password input

```
<input type="password" autocomplete="new-password" [(ngModel)]="driver.pwdAm"
              [placeholder]="'DRIVERS.FORM.PWD' | translate" [matTooltip]="'DRIVERS.FORM.PWD' | translate">
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add fake input fields to allow that browser use that fake fields and you continuous using yours correctly.

```
<div class='name' *ngIf="COMPTE_FRANCAIS==true">

    <!--  fake fields are a workaround for chrome/opera autofill getting the wrong fields -->
    <input id="username" style="display:none" type="text" name="fakeusernameremembered">
    <input id="password" style="display:none" type="password" name="fakepasswordremembered">

    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]="driver.loginAm"
      [placeholder]="'DRIVERS.FORM.LOGIN' | translate" [matTooltip]="'DRIVERS.FORM.LOGIN' | translate">
    <input type="password" autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]="driver.pwdAm"
      [placeholder]="'DRIVERS.FORM.PWD' | translate" [matTooltip]="'DRIVERS.FORM.PWD' | translate">

    <a href="https://authps-espacepro.ameli.fr/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"
      style="margin-top: auto;">
      <button class="btn btn-ameli">
        <img src="./../../../../assets/img/ameli.png">
      </button>
    </a>

</div>
```

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: sorry it doesn't work